# How to create keyspace in start of cassandra docker image or on start of spring boot app

Tags: spring-boot, docker, cassandra

I need to connect a spring boot app with Cassandra DB in docker container and i need to create keyspace on spring app startup or even on Cassandra container start. How can i achieve this?

Comment: That's not really how Stack Overflow works.  The best way to get good answers, is to ask a good question containing code (you have tried) and any error messages that you are getting.  For your particular case, my suggestion is for you to read up on Docker entrypoint files (that's where I do it).  https://success.docker.com/article/use-a-script-to-initialize-stateful-container-data

Answer (score 1):

In your spring-boot java config you can have a bean which does this.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:cassandra.properties")
public class DaoConfig {
     @Bean
     public CassandraSessionManager getCassandraSessionManager() {
         return new CassandraSessionManager();
     }
}
```

If you are using datastax's cassandra java-driver, you can create your keyspace like below.

```
String query = "CREATE KEYSPACE mykeyspace WITH replication = 
{'class':'SimpleStrategy','replication_factor':1};";              
Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("127.0.0.1").build();
Session session = cluster.connect();
session.execute(query);
```

More common usecase is to connect to an existing keyspace, you can do that like https://github.com/joychakravarty/JNotes/blob/jnotes_withSpring/src/main/java/com/jc/jnotes/dao/remote/cassandra/CassandraSessionManager.java

Comment: This will work, but (despite all the examples out there) I really don't recommend that folks modify Cassandra schema from within their application.  Cassandra just isn't very good at managing schema disagreement with concurrent schema modification requests.